# Contextual Action Bar doesn't close with large number of items

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, contextual-action-bar

I'm having a really weird issue with my `contextual action bar` that is set to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`.  I'm using this code to auto-close the CAB after a menu item is selected:

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode, android.view.MenuItem item) {

        /* menu actions preformed here */

       mode.finish();
}
```

Now if I select one or two items in the `ListView` it closes fine, but if I select more, usually over ten, the CAB doesn't auto-close.  The actions that are being performed in `onActionItemClicked` are database calls for each item selected, so not sure if that has something to do with.  I'm also using `ActionbarSherlock` if that makes a difference.

Comment: same issue here... let me know if you figure it out.